# SQLite as a Session Storage

Tags: php, sqlite, model-view-controller, memcached, session-cookies

I wanted to know is it a good practice to use SQLite as a main session storage or at least as a backup session storage with primary memcached?

Could you give me some pros and cons?

*(I am building a MVC Framework for education purposes and was thinking of different possibilities and implemetations)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SQLite Pros**

- faster than file based sessions
- can be distributed where file based sessions are more awkward

**SQLite Cons**

- requires SQLite which creates a dependency and something else to monitor
- harder to implement that native file based sessions
- large applications can quickly kill the sql table by so many read and write requests, fragmentation, index updates, etc especially with almost every page hit hitting that specific table

**Even Better Solution - Memcache**

Since sessions are usually accessed with every page hit it would make sense to use the fastest mechanism possible without all the overhead of a database layer while still allowing it to work in a distributed system (multiple PHP servers for example).

Use Memcache which is well tested with PHP and you can even integrate memcache sessions just by modifying a few php.ini settings or for more fine grained control (or to use other software like redis) you can create your own custom session handler.

This has different pros and cons

**Memcache Pros**

- Very very fast
- Scales well
- Easy to implement via PHP.INI

**Memcache Cons**

- Another service that has the potential to crash and requires monitoring
- Uses RAM which is usually a limited resource compaired to HDD space and also requires monitoring

*Though you should be using other software that monitor both those things or write a cron job script that checks the memcache service is still running - but thats another question and answer for another day. Point is, those cons can be lessened to some degree.*

**Further reading on the topics covered**

- [Memcache sessions using PHP.INI](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php)
- [Redis](http://redis.io/)
- [Custom PHP Session Handler](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php)

Comment: OK What if I use them both if accessible that is.. Lets say the primary is memcache/d and when a new one is created to be added in the SQLite and the SQLite to be used only if memcache/d is down ?

Comment: Primary and secondary sessions? Ay!? No, stick to just memcache - you would not believe just how much faster it is compaired to SQLite or file based sessions. If memcache is down, restart it! Under a site with heavy traffic, if memcache was at say 50% use, when it falls back to SQLite it will most likely crash that anyway!!! You will get a lot more performance out of memcache than sqlite meaning you can't fall back on it. If you wanted to fall back on something, it must at least be memory based (APC for example, but, that won't distribute as it's only a local cache).

Comment: Isn't it better to have an fail-safe alternative ?

Comment: For the amount of time it would take to restart memcache and the fact you can distribute memcache over multiple servers - it has the redundancy built in so even if one crashes, the other can still take over.

Comment: So the memcache instances/servers have to be like mirrors or i got this wrong ?

Comment: You're best bet is to research a little on google as you're now deviating from the original question and google will better answer than myself through comments.

Comment: I know this is an old topic but I'd like to chime in. Memcached to me is great is all you seek is speed, but what about durability and persistence? Rebooting a server or Memcached instance instantly loses all of your sessions. If you run a website where people are logged in all day, they won't be very pleased at all. Better solution (Again my opinion) is Redis. You get the speed of working in RAM and the optional persistence.

Comment: "If you run a website where people are logged in all day, they won't be very pleased at all" depends how you implemented it? If a remember me style cookie gets sent over with the request you could easily log them back in ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sessions based on files are a bad idea, because the file will be locked if you dont close the write access to the session ( session_write_close(); ). But why should you limit yourself/theServer when you just have to use sqlite to avoid this problem?

so 
sqlite pro:
- easy to use (change php.ini config):

```
session.save_handler = sqlite
session.save_path = "/path/sessions.db"
```

- faster to load pages (session can now work parallel)
- faster with ajax
- build in functionality

sqlite con

- slower to write to session

i would like to use apc, but then i need to implementation and i'm worried that it could end in security issues...

Comment: If you use APC you could encrypt the data in the sessions but it would consume you more execution time.

Comment: Thanks for including sample config too and mentioning the `blocking` issue with files.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's file bases session is pretty good and fast, using SQLite for storing session will only add overhead to your session management.